# DB design to store flight route cost

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to create a db to store flight routes and also the cost for each route. So far this is my current design

```
+---------+---------+------+
| start   | dest    | cost |
+---------+---------+------+
| Chicago | NY      |  250 |
| Denver  | Chicago |  250 |
| Denver  | NY      |  400 |
| Denver  | SF      |  250 |
| SF      | Chicago |  550 |
| SF      | Denver  |  300 |
| SF      | NY      |  700 |
+---------+---------+------+
```

Using this design, the query to get cost price will be really simple. For example:

```
select cost from routes where start = 'SF' and dest = 'NY';
```

But I have to define each 'start' to each 'dest' to get the cost.
If want to store like 1000 airports, 1000 airlines, and each of the airport are connected. So maybe it will stored like millions of data? and the query will be heavy.

is there any other design to store the flight route so I don't have to store millions data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make a table of routes, airlines, and a join table.  Ultimately the 3rd table will have a lot of records, but the ids should perform better.

```
Routes
+----+---------+---------+
| id | start   | dest    |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | Chicago | NY      |
|  2 | Denver  | Chicago |
|  3 | Denver  | NY      |
|  4 | Denver  | SF      |
+----+---------+---------+

Airlines
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | American  |
|  2 | Delta     |
|  3 | Southwest |
|  4 | Denver    |
+----+-----------+

AirlineRoutes
+------------+----------+------+
| airline_id | route_id | cost |
+------------+----------+------+
| 1          |  1       |  250 |
| 1          |  2       |  250 |
| 2          |  1       |  400 |
+------------+----------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

"really simple" -- Oh?  I see 3 ways to get from SF to NY:

- SF non-stop to NY,
- SF -> Denver -> NY,
- SF -> Chicago -> NY

Plus I see a way that gets into a loop (SF->Denver->SF->...).

I suspect the algorithm for this would best be done in an app language, not SQL.

According to Google, there are 102,465 flights per day worldwide.  Your table would work fine with that many rows.

However, I would use the standard codes for airports (SFO, ORD, etc) and for Airlines.  Then have another table for looking up full names, if you like.